# How to change the width of reCAPTCHA?

Tags: css, responsive-design, captcha, recaptcha

I'm used [Google reCAPTCHA 2](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/) in my project and want to set awidth for the CAPTCHA, because my project should have responsive design, but don't know how I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a technique I'm using where you adjust the transform property and dynamically get the scale value. This is great if you have various form sizes. If you only have 1 or 2 forms, it would be best to use a CSS class. See this article for reference: https://www.geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    /**
     * We're in a timer b/c something weird happens to the container at load time.
     * If that does not happen for you, by all means remove the timer.
     * Container is the recaptcha div
     * Check if the captcha is bigger than the parent container
     * If so, scale it down. Be warned, if you scale too much
     * things get a bit weird.
     */
    var childWidth = container.offsetWidth,
        parentWidth = container.parentElement.offsetWidth;

    if (childWidth >= parentWidth) {
        /* console.log('too big'); */
        container.style.transform = 'scale(' + parentWidth / childWidth + ')';
        container.style.transformOrigin = '0px 50% 0px';
    }
    clearTimeout(timer);
}, (60 * 2));
```

**UPDATE:** Google has added support for a smaller size via a parameter. Have a look at the docs - https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
#recaptcha_widget_div {
    overflow: visible;
    transform: scaleX(0.9);
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below style properties worked for me. Add to specific div element immediately above iframe.

```
html #recaptcha_area, html #recaptcha_table {
 transform: scale(0.77);
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.77);
 transform-origin: 0 0; 
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```